# A less lousy sticky nav on iOS?

Tags: jquery, ios, navigation, nav, sticky

My goal is rather straightforward and not too fancy: a want a secondary navigation bar to be set in a fixed position at the very top of the screen when the user scrolls down the page.

My script is simple as well:

```
var stickySubnavTop = $('#subnav').offset().top;  

    var stickySubnav = function(){  
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

        if (scrollTop > stickySubnavTop-28) {   
            $('#subnav').addClass('sticky');  
        } else {  
            $('#subnav').removeClass('sticky');   
            }  
    };  

    stickySubnav();  

    $(window).scroll(function() {  
    stickySubnav();  
    });
```

Works like a charm on all desktop browsers, not so much on iOS. Now, here's the thing: **I'm fully aware that iOS freezes the DOM when scrolling**. Nonetheless, I'd like to know if there's any way to make the effect feel less abrupt.

When looking for an answer, I came across a few touch events I wasn't familiar with.
The `touchmove` listening event in particular caught my attention, and I figured I could try and make my script run with it:

```
$(document).on('touchmove', function() {
       stickySubnav; 
    });
```

What this does is run the script when the user scrolls *while keeping their finger on the screen*. It doesn't work when they launch the scroll with inertia, but still, it is enough to make the effect smoother, as the content of the page makes it so that the user is less likely to scroll quickly.

The problem is: running that script this way makes the scrolling a little choppy on older phones. I found that A5-class processors can handle it just fine, but anything less powerful wouldn't be able to deal with it while maintaining a perfectly smooth scrolling experience.

My question is: is there any way I could tell that script to only run once every X milliseconds, or any other way to make the whole experience less frustrating?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

On iOS 6+, try CSS3 sticky position:

```
/* 
 * same as position:relative as long as the element is more than 28px 
 * from the top of the viewport.  Then, it is the same as position: fixed 
 */
#subnav {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky /* future compatibility */
    top: 28px; /* viewport top threshold */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't this line:

`position: sticky /* future compatibility */`

have a semicolon?

`position: sticky; /* future compatibility */`

Comment: This should not have been posted as an answer. You should have left a comment on the original answer stating they missed the semicolon after `position: sticky`.